# How to get the validator method work for Checkbox

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a validation method to the jquery Form  validate

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.addMethod(
            "FHM",
            function (value, element) {
                var StdHrs  =$('#frmStdHours').val();       
                var OTHrs   =$('#frmOTHours').val();        
                var TrvHrs  =$('#frmTravelHours').val();
                var SUM     =StdHrs+OTHrs+TrvHrs;
                if(SUM > 4)
                    return (value ==false);
                else
                    return (value == true);
            },
            "Please Change the actual hours to less than 4 or Uncheck  Four Hour Min."
    );
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Form").validate({   
            rules: 
            {
                fld4HrMin:
                {
                    FHM:true
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

html

```
<form id="Form">
  <input type="checkbox" name="fld4HrMin" id="fld4HrMin">
  <input type="text"  size="5" name="frmOTHours" id="frmOTHours" value="0" >
  <input type="text"  size="5" name="frmTravelHours" id="frmTravelHours" value="0">
  <input type="text"  size="5" name="frmStdHours" id="frmStdHours" value="0" >
</form>
```

this is not working---the error is the error message is being shown up always

What I am trying to do is if sum of the three input boxes is greater than 4 ,if it is the checkbox should be unchecked if it is less than 4 the check box should be checked.

Comment: @JamesMontagne fixed his indentation

Comment: Try adding `parseInt(x,10)` around the values.  eg `var StdHrs  = parseInt($('#frmStdHours').val(), 10);`

Comment: @Rocket ,No luck it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two issues here,

the first, try doing the parseInt as @Rocket said,

The second, you logic has some issues, if you change it to this, it works as expected:

```
             if(SUM > 4)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
```

Comment: Hey DevDude,I tried that one too but still the error comes up no matter whether the check box is checked or not.And also I tried giving parseInt also,it doesnot work even

Comment: I tried reproducing the code, the behavior I got with the bits of code was this: if i clicked the checkbox and the rules didn't match, I would get the error message, otherwise it wouldnt show. But you are saying that it needs to check whether the checkbox is checked or not as well? It looks to me like you have some logic-related issues there. I would analyze the problem again and start from scratch.